# Launching Safari App without using any specific url from an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari, nsurl

In one of my iOS App, I have to just launch the Safari App and not open some specific Url in Safari which can be achieved by this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

But I only need to launch safari App with last tab open (in the same state that I leave before entering that iOS App).

Any suggestion and help will be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: You want to just launch safari without any URL?

Comment: Yup I want to just launch the Safari App as I left it before.

Comment: Make the string just "http://" and try?

Comment: It will open new blank tab in safari, not as it was when you close it.

Comment: But what it the case when user should open safari without opening any URL?

Comment: His question is that  "I have to just launch the Safari App and not open some specific Url in Safari ". He isn't opening any link but he is opening safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we can open a specific app from safari. You have to create a custom url scheme for the application and open that link from safari like any other link is opened from safari.

Create a custom url scheme like

myApp://

Then open it from safari e.g on onClick of  button.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://about:blank"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

Swift 3.0

```
UIApplication.shared().openURL(URL(string: "http://about:blank")!)
```

Hope It will help you.

Add Comment if you require any other information.

Comment: You just mentioned this didn't work in the comment. And now when it worked for you, you deleted the comment and wrote the same answer.

Comment: Ok. That's fair. Removing my down vote and upvoting it.

Comment: @Irfan you can tick as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Only need to launch safari App and restore the last tab open(in the same state that I leave before entering that iOS App) and not wants to open the blank page.

Comment: @Irfan ok Let me check if I can solve this. I drafted and post answer mean while you edit the question. Thats I don't read. anyways let me check if I can help you !!!